# Looking to identify an old National 8-pin DIP (M8440)

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

I have a rail of these 8-pin DIP's that I'm guessing was bought 15 - 20 years ago.  My guess is that they could be op-amps or comparators.  There are 3 printed lines on these chips:

- N M8440
- 28930
- 35-00

Where "N" is the double-wave National symbol.  Any idea what they are?

[image]

Comment: Could you attach a picture? That 8 can be a B, 0 an O, etc. A good picture can make it unambiguous.

Comment: I'll attach a photo tomorrow if it helps, but I'm pretty sure it's an 8.

Comment: M8440 looks like a Natsemi date code for week 40 of 1984  could it be 30 years ago?

Comment: Lookup “LM1496.   M8440 NSC”. But this is DIP16...It was always wwyy Jason from what I recall

Comment: 2nd number is often customer p/n

Answer (score 1):

Date codes are YYWW so they are 35 years old. The other two lines look like a customer part number, so there probably isn't a way to find out a mfg number. However opamp pinout is standard so you could just plug it in and see if it works.
Addendum: I have found Ibias, slew rate, and Iq to be most helpful in identifying unknown parts.
The picture confirms what I said in the first two sentences. I have up voted for being the only person I have seen so far that supplied a good photo.

Comment: So it has to be a part that NS was manufacturing 35 years ago. Here's one possibility:- LM318N https://img.alicdn.com/tfscom/i4/TB1C_QEFFXXXXaxaXXXXXXXXXXX_!!0-item_pic.jpg

Comment: I think we did use the 318 for some of our designs, but then I think that chip went eol maybe 10 years ago?

Comment: I still have NS data books from this era so could list some candidates if you supplied some performance numbers, I find Ib, Iq, and slew rate easiest to measure and most helpful in identifying possiblities.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly a 2K bit I2C EEPROM similar to CSI24WC02P (similar to 24C02 generic parts).

[image]